# Ruby script cannot find table from PostgreSQL database (PG::UndefinedTable)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I'm trying to interact with my PostgreSQL database. I installed the 'pg' gem, and I'd like to execute a very simple script like this one:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open('127.0.0.1' , 5432, nil, nil, 'postgres', 'postgres', 'admin')  
res  = conn.exec('SELECT * FROM testtable')
```

But all I get is:

> testdb.rb:4:in `exec': ERROR:  relation "testtable" does not exist (PG::UndefinedTable)

If you have any clue or sample code, that would help a lot!

Comment: Have you created table `testtable`?

Comment: Yep of course and a few rows in it.

Comment: have you used double quotes during creating table "TestTable" or smth similar?

Comment: No. It is all lower case.

Comment: Have you created `testtable` in `postgres` database?  Your code works for me for a table that I have in my database, so either you using wrong table name or database name

Comment: I realized I had two conflicted postgres databases on my local host! It is now fixed! Thank you @WandMaker

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). It's much easier and more portable than using Pg directly.